# I'm not getting HTML tag while parsing

Tags: perl, parsing, web, mechanize

The fragment of HTML code which i want to parse is like this:

```
<ul class="authors">
    <li class="author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a href="/search?facet-creator=%22Charles+L.+Fefferman%22" itemprop="name">Charles L. Fefferman</a>,
    </li>
    <li class="author" itemprop="author" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a href="/search?facet-creator=%22Jos%C3%A9+L.+Rodrigo%22" itemprop="name">JosÃ© L. Rodrigo</a>
    </li>
```

I want to extract whole `<a>` elements, but while I'm trying to parse it with `WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder` the only content I get is the names of the authors. So:

Content I'm expecting:

```
<a href="/search?facet-creator=%22Charles+L.+Fefferman%22" itemprop="name">Charles L. Fefferman</a>,

<a href="/search?facet-creator=%22Jos%C3%A9+L.+Rodrigo%22" itemprop="name">JosÃ© L. Rodrigo</a>
```

Content I'm receiving:

```
Charles L. Fefferman,
José L. Rodrigo
```

Here is the code responsible for parsing this:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
WWW::Mechanize::TreeBuilder->meta->apply($mech);
$mech->get($addressdio);

my @authors = $mech->look_down('class', 'author');

print "Authors: <br />";
foreach ( @authors ) {
    say $_->as_text(), "<br />";
}
```

I thought that it could be to do with `as_text()`, and also that while CGI gets HTML it doesn't take it as text.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to the question and accept it. That way others will find it, and people trying to help will see more easily that there is already a solution. You can also [edit] the question and remove it there, as it doesn't belong in the question, or just roll back the change. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handled it, but totally different way - using HTML::TagParser:

```
my $html = HTML::TagParser->new("overwrite.xml");
my @li = $html->getElementsByAttribute('class','author');

foreach(@li){
    my $a = $_->firstChild();
    my $link = $a->getAttribute('href');
    say $_->innerText;

    say $link;
}
```